# Applescript to find a file created closest to a given time - throughout multiple folders

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write a script that will search through 100 folders and find the file created closest to 9am (for example) in each folder.

I am working on a 30 year long timelapse (4 years in already) and I want to be able to find the photo created closest to a certain time of day quickly and efficiently.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

I've started writing the code in applescript but I can't figure out how to compare "date created"

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the file in each folder whose date of creation as that file in that directory is nearest 09:00? Or do you mean you have photos with EXIF data and you want to check the EXIF data for the one nearest 09:00? What do you mean by being *"4 years in"*?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be rather awful trying to do this in **applescript** so I did it in `bash` which is installed on all Macs anyway.

You can also call my script from **applescript** anyway, using `do shell script`.

So, you would save the following in your HOME directory as `NearestBirth`:

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# NearestBirth
# Mark Setchell
#
# Usage:
# NearestBirth DIRECTORY H:M:S
# Finds the file in the specified directory with the birth time nearest the 
# specified time.
################################################################################

# Set DEBUG=1 for verbose output, set DEBUG=0 for quiet
DEBUG=1

# Check we have 2 parameters and pick them up
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
   echo "Usage:"
   echo "NearestBirth DIRECTORY H:M:S"
   exit 1
fi

# Pick up parameters
dir=$1
hms=$2

[ $DEBUG -eq 1 ] && echo "DEBUG: dir=$dir, hms=$hms"

################################################################################
# hms2s - convert HH:MM:SS to seconds since midnight
################################################################################
hms2s(){
   IFS=: read h m s <<< "$1"
   ((result=(10#$h*3600)+(10#$m*60)+10#$s))
   echo $result
}

################################################################################
# birthtime - get birthtime of file in seconds since midnight on day of creation
################################################################################
birthtime(){
   # The following command gives the birthtime of a file on macOS
   # stat -f "%SB" someFile.txt
   # Feb  4 18:49:05 2019
   s=$(stat -f "%SB" "$1" | awk '{print $3}')
   result=$(hms2s $s)
   echo $result
}

################################################################################
# main
################################################################################
cd "$top" || { echo "Unable to change to $top"; exit 1; }

# Work out target age of file in seconds since midnight
tgt=$(hms2s "$hms")
[ $DEBUG -eq 1 ] && echo "DEBUG: Target age in seconds=$tgt"

shopt -s nullglob

nearestTime=100000                # More than number of seconds in a day - must surely be beaten
nearestFile="ERROR: None found"   # Must surely get overwritten

# Iterate over all files in the directory
for f in *; do
   birth=$(birthtime "$f")
   ((diff=tgt-birth))
   [ $diff -lt 0 ] && ((diff=-1*diff))
   if [ $diff -lt $nearestTime ] ; then
       nearestTime=$diff
       nearestFile="$f"
       [ $DEBUG -eq 1 ] && echo "DEBUG: New nearest ($birth): $f"
   fi
done
echo "$nearestFile"
```

Then you would start **Terminal** and make the script executable with:

```
chmod +x $HOME/NearestBirth
```

You can then run the script like this, to find the nearest file birth to 09:00:00 in directory `/Users/mark/StackOverflow`:

```
$HOME/NearestBirth  "/Users/mark/StackOverflow"  09:00:00
```

**Sample Output (with DEBUG=1)**

```
./NearestBirth /Users/mark/StackOverflow 09:00:00
DEBUG: dir=/Users/mark/StackOverflow, hms=09:00:00
DEBUG: Target age in seconds=32400
DEBUG: New nearest (64051): 16bit.py
DEBUG: New nearest (60948): 2d-plot
DEBUG: New nearest (46205): 45.py
DEBUG: New nearest (26224): 565.py
DEBUG: New nearest (38203): HSV.py
DEBUG: New nearest (32131): IMBoxAreas
DEBUG: New nearest (32235): restore.py
restore.py
```

**Keywords**: macOS, OSX, file birth time, birth time, creation time, stat, mtime, ctime, atime

Comment: **Note**: I presume you can recurse through multiple directories easily enough in Applescript - if I did it in bash, you would have to untangle the results from all the directories.

Comment: **Note**: If your locale causes file times to be printed in 12hr clock rather than 24hr clock, i.e. 5pm rather than 17:00, you will need to change `hms2s()` and if you see `pm` in the string, add `12*3600` to move past midday.

Comment: I agree AppleScript is not the way to go and `bash` is much more efficient for this; however, the OP said "...a script that will search through 100 folders and find the file created closest to 9am (for example) in each folder.", which I take to mean a recursive search of all 100 folders at one time, not having to execute the script manually 100 times as would have to be done as the script is presently coded. Certainly worth a +1 anyway.

Comment: @user3439894 It is pretty simple to recurse, I actually wrote it that way originally, but then I figured OP would have to parse all the output to get the answer for each directory and he can presumably recurse pretty simply in applescript. Let's see what OP says, if they ever log in again! Thanks for vote :-)